# aiming to link goog sheets data into a goog form but getId is not defined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

below is my attempt to link sheets to forms, however, one line is not working and unable to overcome, appreciate any advise. Thank you.

my entire code is as below.

```
var ssID = "<id1>";

var formID = "<id2>";

var wsData = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("data");


var form = FormApp.openById(formID);

function main(){
  
  var labels = wsData.getRange(1,1,1,wsData.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  
  
}

-------

function updateDropdownUsingTitle(title, values) {

  var items = form.getItems();
  var titles = items.map(function(item){
    return item.getTitle();
  });
    
  var pos = titles.indexOf(title);
  var item = items[pos];
  var itemID = item.getId(); //this line is not defined
    
  updateDropdown(itemID, values);
}

------

function updateDropdown(id, values) {
  var item  = form.getItemById(id);
  item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values)
```

Comment: Hi, I posted an answer even though you didn't provide the code related to how you're calling `updateDropdownUsingTitle`. Let me know if my answer solves your issue. Otherwise, please update your question to include the requested code.

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

If you're getting the error `Cannot read property 'getId' of undefined`, this means there is no Item in your Form that has the provided `title`. That's because `titles.indexOf(title)` will return `-1` if the provided `title` is not found in `titles`, and therefore, `items[-1]` will return `undefined`.

#### Solution:

Make sure the `title` you are providing as an argument when calling `updateDropdownUsingTitle` corresponds to an Item in the Form. Also, this function's code could be much simplified through the use of [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). For example, you could use this instead:

```
function updateDropdownUsingTitle(title, values) {
  var items = form.getItems();
  var item = items.find(item => item.getTitle() === title);
  if (item) updateDropdown(item.getId(), values);
}
```

**Note**: In the sample above, the function is checking whether `item` is defined before trying to update it. Because of this, if the provided `title` doesn't correspond to an Item, no error will be given; it just won't update anything.

Comment: thank you! I realised it is because i need a function that calls this function and then the problem goes away!